# Saving polygonized raster file to shapefile failed

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, polygonize, save

I have a raster that I have polygonized (raster to vector) with QGIS 3.20.3. The result is a temp layer that can be displayed in the canvas.

When I try to save the features to shapefile it runs until 99% and then nothing happens. The same happens when I try to use fix geometries. What can be the reason?

Comment: that works, I can safe the file, but when I try to fix geometries or dissolve or try to delete features afterwards I get the same problem

Comment: o.k. that finally works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector layers created by polygonizing rasters can be huge. Maybe it is too big too fix everything in one step.

Try:

1. [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/splitvectorlayer.html)
2. Fix geometries on each split output
3. Merge the fixed geometry outputs

And use geopackage output in all stages.